# Is there an easy way to customize a toolbar from an activity from within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back, hamburger-menu

I am working on an app where I use **one activity** to load all my fragments in.
In one of my fragments I made a **listview** where when clicked on an item you get sent to another fragment.

On every fragment i have a hamburger menu to navigate between my fragments, but on my "details fragment" I want a back icon instead of the hamburger menu, is there an easy way to replace the main toolbar and replace it with a toolbar with back button on.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but it may actually be easier in this case to open it in a new Activity that has a back button.  Then going "home" and all other stuff would be handled already. This of course is assuming that the details fragment is the only thing showing (which I assume since you want to display the back).  It also frees up your Fragment to be used in other places in the future and you don't have to deal with cases where you *don't* want the back button.

Comment: use getactivity to get the activity you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details fragment should be inside new activity. It's not good practice to put next level navigation into existing Activity. You can find more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/design-navigation/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and add the back button

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        setToolbar();
        }

         private void setToolbar() {
         Toolbar ftoolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         if (ftoolbar != null) {
              ftoolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_button);
              ftoolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                }
            });
        }

    }
```